# Automate an unmodified remote browser

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, capybara, automated-tests

I would like to do automated testing on a remote firefox browser. I can't install any software on the machine with the browser installed on it. I can't run any console line application, it is in a 'sandbox'. I can however add any javascript to the pages we are testing.

Would the JasonWireProtocol help with this? https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol

Any other ideas would be appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: almost every OS has a "remote desktop" capability. you can remote into the machine and do your testing.

Comment: Remote desktop is not an option due to our set-up. Also I want to do automated testing, I don't think you can do this via remote desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending what u need to test, I would just write the tests in JS, sent the result via AJAX to the server and reload the page.

If u need a live communication, WebSockets or a LongPolling can help u, but its nothing special!

Comment: This is along the lines we are thinking, I just want to make sure we are not re-inventing the wheel.